# Ormlite setup without using base activities

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I'm using [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) in an android project, and I'm not wanting to use the extended activities because I'm inserting values into the database on an AsyncTask.

In the docs it says:

"If you do not want to extend the `OrmLiteBaseActivity` and other base classes then you will need to duplicate their functionality. You will need to call `OpenHelperManager.getHelper(Context context, Class openHelperClass)` at the start of your code, save the helper and use it as much as you want, and then call `OpenHelperManager.release()` when you are done with it."

It also says to add the database helper class in the `strings.xml`, which I have.  So I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

I'm using a class called `DataAccess` for my data tier that looks like this:

```
public class DataAccess {
    private Context context;
    private DBHelper dbHelper;

    public DataAccess(Context _context) {
        this.context = _context;
        dbHelper = getDBHelper(_context);
    }

    private DBHelper getDBHelper(Context context) {
        if (dbHelper == null) {
            dbHelper = (DBHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DBHelper.class);
        }
        return dbHelper;
    }
}
```

And I'm using the extended helper class:

```
public class DBHelper extends OrmLiteSqliteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "database.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    private Dao<SomeObject, Integer> someObjectTable = null;
    private ConnectionSource connectionSource = null;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource) {
        this.connectionSource = connectionSource;
        try {
            TableUtils.createTable(connectionSource, SomeObject.class);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, ConnectionSource connectionSource, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    }

    public Dao<SomeObject, Integer> getSomeObjectDao() throws SQLException {
        if (someObjectTable == null) {
            dateTable = getDao(SomeObject.class);
        }
        return someObjectTable;
    }
```

The idea is to create the `DataAccess` class and have it create the `DBHelper` if it hasn't already.

Can someone tell me if this is right or wrong, or if I'm on the right path?

Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> I'm using ORMLite in an android project, and I'm not wanting to use the extended activities because I'm inserting values into the database on an AsyncTask.

You are on the right track but a little off @Matt.  Frankly I'd never done a project without extending our base classes.  But it is a good exercise so I've created this [ORMLite example project](http://ormlite.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/ormlite/examples/android/HelloAndroidNoBase/src/com/example/hellonobase/) which uses an `Activity` and manages its own helper.

Your `DBHelper` class is fine but really you do not need your `DataAccess` class.  In each of your activities (or services...) you will need to have something like the following:

```
private DBHelper dbHelper = null;

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (dbHelper != null) {
        OpenHelperManager.releaseHelper();
        dbHelper = null;
    }
}

private DBHelper getHelper() {
    if (dbHelper == null) {
        dbHelper = (DBHelper)OpenHelperManager.getHelper(this, DBHelper.class);
    }
    return dbHelper;
}
```

You [obviously], then use this in your code by doing something like:

```
Dao<SomeObject, Integer> someObjectDao = getHelper().getSomeObjectDao();
```

So whenever you call `getHelper()` the first time, it will get the helper through the manager, establishing the connection to the database.  Whenever your application gets destroyed by the OS, it will release the helper -- possibly closing the underlying database connection if it is the last release.

Notice that the `OpenHelperManager.getHelper()` needs the `Context` as the first argument in case you do this without even an `Activity` base class.

**Edit:**

If you do want to create a `DataAccess` type class to centralize the handling of the helper class then you will need to make the methods static and do your own usage counter.  If there are multiple activities and background tasks calling `getHelper()` then the question is when do you call `releaseHelper()`?  You'll have to increment a count for each get and only call release when the counter gets back to 0.  But even then, I'm not 100% sure how many lines you'd save out of your activity class.

Comment: The idea behind the DataAccess method is to perform all the data operations in that class. It is sometimes used in an activity and sometimes in the background.  Is that the wrong way to use it?

Comment: I've edited my answer @Matt with details about a centralized static class.

Comment: Would the class have to be static?  What if I created the centralized class on the onCreate, and called a method in the centralized class to release the helper in the onDestroy? Wouldn't that do the same thing?

Comment: That's fine but if each of your `Activity` classes did this then there would be multiple instances.  You just need somehow to ensure there is a single instance of this centralized class.

Comment: @Gray what if the DataAccess class was a singleton which had a getInstance() method that took a Context as a parameter? The getInstance() method (or the private constructor) could make a call like OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context.getApplicationContext(). Does this still work? Also, if the singleton was constructed like this, would a call to releaseHelper still be necessary?

Comment: @Gray, as @adstro asked above, would making the `DataAccess` class a singleton, remove the necessity of releasing the helper?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure @Hadi.  As I understand it, one of the complexities is when an application is stopped but not unloaded.  If the database connections and the internal ORMLite stuff not released then when the application comes back, certain objects can hold connections to stale database connections.  I think you still need to release stuff.  Anyone else know the answer here?

Comment: So what if I have multiple model classes and then I want to save all the query like `getById` , `getAll` methods in a `repo` class. I will have to define all the method names in the `helper` class but how to refator it so that corresponding `getById` , `getAll` will be available for particular class. Like if I want to get a `Category` object by its `id` i want a `CategoryRepo` which has `getById` method and will return the particular Category and the same process for `Transaction`.

Answer (score 2):

I could nitpick but essentially you are doing it correct.

The call

```
dbHelper = (DBHelper) OpenHelperManager.getHelper(context, DBHelper.class);
```

Looks up the `DBHelper` class and instantiates it for the context. If you have defined it in your strings.xml, you can leave off the DBHelper.class at the end.

`onUpgrade` in you `DBHelper.java`, you may want to consider dropping the table you create in `onCreate` and then calling `onCreate` (to make sure you don't have conversion issues from update to update). You could do a more complex update if you wanted.

Other than that, it looks good. If you end up wanting data accessory methods for your DB objects beyond the base DAO methods, you will eventually want to create more thorough implementations of your object DAOs, but this is a good start.

Comment: How do you define the database class athe the strings.xml?

Comment: <string name="open_helper_classname">com.foo.bar.DatabaseHelper</string>

Comment: That field being a string smells. It could just as easily have been made a `<meta-data>` in `AndroidManifest.xml`.