# Using a TabListener for triggering Activities with ActionBarSherlock

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, actionbarsherlock

I have had some trouble finding an example I understand for using ActionBarSherlock. I can implement the `TabNavigation.java` example that comes with the download. I'm not sure how to extend this example so that it triggers a new activity but still keeps the tabs displayed.  Here's the example that I've implemented:

```
package com.actionbarsherlock.sample.demos;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.Tab;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class TabNavigation extends SherlockActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private TextView mSelected;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setTheme(SampleList.THEME); //Used for theme switching in samples
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.tab_navigation);
        mSelected = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        getSupportActionBar().setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 3; i++) {
            ActionBar.Tab tab = getSupportActionBar().newTab();
            tab.setText("Tab " + i);
            tab.setTabListener(this);
            getSupportActionBar().addTab(tab);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
        mSelected.setText("Selected: " + tab.getText());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction transaction) {
    }
}
```

I believe I need to create a new "Listener" class and pass that to the `.setTabListener()` method. I want to stick with Activities (not Fragments) as I have a pretty complex implementation of ORMLite and I'm not sure how to use ORMLite with Fragments yet.

I want to add a new tab labeled "Profile" which triggers `ProfileActivity.class`.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess that TabListener is supposed to work with Fragments and FragmentTransaction. You will have to move your code from ProfileActivity to a new ProfileFragment class and add it with the FragmentTransaction you receive by the listener.

I would suggest you to add ViewPagerIndicator library on your project, just like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10082163/actionbarsherlock-tabs-multi-fragments). A ViewPager is just like tabs plus the swype movement to navigate between them.

Comment: thanks. the reason i'm kinda stuck is because I'm also using ORMLite which has its own ORMLiteActivity class. There is no ORMLiteFragmentActivity class.  :(

Comment: This is bad, I'm not familiar with ORMLite, but I think that must be a workaround for Fragments. Have you tried something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7656539/ormlite-setup-without-using-base-activities)?

Comment: It actually turned out to not be very difficult. The ORMLiteActivity class is just a small convenience class. They actually explain how to write your code if you would prefer not to use it. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the reason I'm not finding the example I am looking for is because you just can't use the action bar persistently with Activities. Comments or a better answer would be much appreciated.  :)

Comment: That's not true. See my answer.

Comment: What answer? Don't see it.