# Android - Using ActionBarSherlock along with ORMLite

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, ormlite, extends

I have a parent Activity that ALL other activities in my app extend from, let's call it `MainActivity`. At first it was extending OrmLiteBaseActivity, like so :

```
public class MainActivity extends OrmLiteBaseActivity<DatabaseHelper>
```

Now that I want to use `ActionBarSherlock` in my app, I have to extend from `SherlockActivity`... But I can't extend from two classes at once.

Has anybody worked with `ORMLite` and `ActionBarSherlock` before ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7662537/1318946

Answer (score 0):

As said by [PratikButani](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1318946/pratik-butani): I ended up using ORMLite's `OpenHelperManager` for each time I wanted to used the database.

Link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/7662537/1318946